# Домен для сайта Django

Tags: python, django

Вот у меня есть созданный и готовый django сайт. Пр умолчанию он доступен лишь на адресе 127.0.0.0:8888.
Как подключить домен к моему сайту?

Comment: Купить домен, прописать на него IP-адрес сервера и в настройках джанги прописать `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['вашдомен']`, остальное по инструкции https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5